# Does `mv --context` (for selinux, a.k.a. -Z) correctly apply labels recursively to directory contents?

Tags: selinux, recursive, mv

`mv -Z` applies the default selinux context.  Does it differ from all other invocations of `mv`, and work on all the files in a moved directory individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/b
$ ls -Z -d a a/b
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 a
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 a/b
$ strace -f mv -Z a ~/.local/share/Trash/files
...
open("/home/alan/.local/share/Trash/files/a/b", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
...
fgetxattr(3, "security.selinux", "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0", 255) = 37
fsetxattr(3, "security.selinux", "unconfined_u:object_r:data_home_t:s0", 37, 0) = 0
...
$ cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files
$ ls -Zd a a/b
unconfined_u:object_r:data_home_t:s0 a
unconfined_u:object_r:data_home_t:s0 a/b
```

---

This also introduced the possibility that moving a directory within a single filesystem will fail part-way through.  I.e. due to lack of disk space when changing the labels.  The impact of this is mitigated as the relabel happens as a second step.  The initial move operation is still by a single atomic `rename`.  This means the labels would be inconsistent, but the files will be consistent in every other way.  It should be simple to fix the labels once space becomes available.