# How to access another user's folder from another user account

Tags: kali-linux, users, root, non-root-user

I have some downloads in my **root** user **/root/Downloads** folder. How can I access them from another `not-root-user` account?

Comment: set not-root-user as root group beside user group. not root user can access root thru root group.

Answer (score 6):

It would be possible to access the root's files/directories by simply changing the permissions.
However I don't recommend to do so because this would be a big security hole. However on personal computer, it won't be such a big issue.
Still, if you want to achieve this, you would need to add the following permissions flags to the `/root` directory:

`x` - this means that you can open/access the directory (`cd` to dir) but you can't read it's contents

`r` - this will allow you to read the directory contents

```
chmod o+x,o+r /root
```

Note: You need to be root (`su root`) when running this command.

The directories inside `/root` should already have read/execute permissions for other users so you shouldn't encounter further issues.

Comment: In order to access the files, only read permissions on the files themselves and `x` permission on all parent directories are required. The example here doesn't grant `x` access to the `/root/Downloads` directory. The `r` on `/root` or `/root/Downloads` isn't strictly speaking required if the user already knows the pathname for the files to access.

Comment: As far as I know, directories inside root should already have  `x` access, by default.

Comment: Depends on the [`umask`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0365/secfile-62/index.html). You're probably right if Kali matches Debian's default `0022`.

Answer (score 3):

By *non-root-user* you mean user that is not in `sudoers` file or just other user that can execute command as root with `sudo`?

In a former occasion - there is **no way** you can access root's home folder.

In the later, you can `sudo su` and you're effectively a *root* user now (if sudo doesn't restrict user's priveleges in any way explicitly).

Comment: This is a good point. [I like `sudo su -`, though nowadays I use `sudo -i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su/218268). There are issues if you want to run GUI apps though.

Answer (score 3):

**Assign the files to a group to which the non-root user belongs to.**

In most modern Linux systems, each user have their own group corresponding to their username.

You can change the group ownership of a file or directory with the [`chgrp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp) command:

```
chgrp group_name pathname
```

However, note that the non-root user also needs directory access for all parent directories, including `/root` itself, to access  files under `/root/Downloads`, which is usually not allowed. Without read priviledges for the parent directories, there's still restrictions on listing the contents of the directory contents for directories under `/root`. In your particular case you would need to give `x` permissions for `/root` and `/root/Downloads` to regular users:

As root:

```
$ chmod o+x /root /root/Downloads
$ chgrp user /root/Downloads/file-non-root-user-needs-to-access
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you want to move them somewhere outside the directory `/root`.  This will help avoid breaking the conventions on security, as others have warned about.

Moving files can be much faster than copying them.  Provided they stay on the same filesystem, all that needs to be written is new file metadata ([example: selinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336999/does-mv-context-for-selinux-a-k-a-z-correctly-apply-labels-recursively3)).

E.g. you can create `/shared-readonly/` and move files there with `mv`.  You don't need to change access modes at all :).  This specific setup (or using `/home/shared-readonly`) is very nice and simple.  I've used it several times myself. (Directories which can be *written* by multiple users are inherently a bit more complex; sadly they're not as robust on Linux as they could be).

You could additionally limit this sharing to `not-root-user`, e.g. to avoid exposing personal data to arbitrary non-root daemons.  Create a group as follows, e.g. here I name it `conspiracy`:

```
groupadd conspiracy
usermod -a -G conspiracy not-root-user
chgrp conspiracy /shared-readonly
chmod o-rx /shared-readonly
```

`not-root-user` will need to log out and back in, before they are recognized as a member of `conspiracy`.  Use `id -a` to check their membership.

If you like to have convenient, visible access to the files as the root user, you can also create a symbolic link to them.  E.g. `ln -s /shared-readonly .`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Kali Linux (Linux basically) and may not work for Ubuntu.

I have a better answer to solve the issue as I've just solved mine.

The most voted answer here doesn't work for Kali Linux (don't know about Ubuntu). The error is 
`chmod: invalid mode: ‘o+x,’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.`

Now the solution without any code:

- Go to the root account and right click the folder you want to share
  with other accounts that is in this case `/root/Downloads`.
- Select properties, go to the permissions tab
- Then select    "Create and Delete files" in the drop-down menu of
  `Others access`.
- Click on `Change Permissions for Enclosed files` and select "read
  and write" and "Create and Delete files" in the drop-down menus of
  Others.
- Click change and Close it. Log out of the account.
- Now log-in into your user account.
- Open Files manager, go to Others -> Computer -> root -> Downloads.
- You'll find your files here.